# Why do warlocks get 9th level spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic, warlock

In the warlock spell list, it says that they have 9th level spells, but they only get up to 5th level spell slots. How does that work?

Comment: It looks like you're asking about D&D 5th edition, but unless you tell us that by adding the dnd-5e tag, we can't really answer this question.

Comment: OP edited in the dnd-5e tag, so it does indeed seem to be a duplicate of that question.

Comment: I'd say it's a [dupe of this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/46274/22566)